# Packaging a .NET web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, windows-installer

I have no prior experience working in the .NET stack. Not sure if this is a common requirement. I have developed a simple .NET web service which accesses the COM library provided by a label printer SDK to send print jobs to the printer connected to my machine.

I need to distribute the web service to clients so that it can be **hosted on their machines locally**. Set up should be minimum - something like an installer which will do the needful to deploy the web service locally.

I assume that any windows machine comes with .NET bundled.
I understand that IIS is the windows equivalent of apache-tomcat. Does is it come bundled with all windows machines? If it does, I figure I can write some scripts to deploy the web service to IIS using the ".deploy" file generated by Visual Studio.

Are there any betters way of doing this ?

So my question is :
How do I distribute a web service that should be be hosted and run locally on the client's machine without forcing the user to download and install a web server and deploy the package?

Edit:

So, I gather IIS is not supported by home editions.

Comment: Care to explain the reason for the downvote?

Comment: You don't distribute a web service - it is hosted. The clients make calls to it.

Comment: @OneFineDay Maybe i need to word it better : I need the web service to be hosted on the client's machine.

Comment: Why do you need that? Typical scenario is service in installed on a server or web hosted site and client make calls to it. Are you doing intranet stuff?

Comment: @OneFineDay The service needs access to a printer connected to the client's machine (not a network printer) and needs to be called from the client's browser

Comment: Then you don't need a web-service. You need a Windows Service. Alternatively, you could self-host the service. See here: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/run-aspnet-web-api-inside-your-application.aspx

Comment: @abhitalks That link looks promising. Thanks. Noob question-  if we go the self-hosted Web API way, can it still be called from the client browser ?

Comment: You will use a url with localhost and port.

Comment: @abhitalks Okay, that sounds good. Is there any built-in support for packaging and distributing ? How do I go about distributing it ?